# Is it common to travel by giving private lessons at host family?

Tags: europe, central-europe

So, a while back I had this idea, to make travelling a bit less expensive, by giving private lessons and tutoring in target country.

In summary, I travel to a target country, stay with some family, they provide food and place to sleep and in exchange I give private lessons, probably to the kids, probably in some school subject.

My question is this.
Is such a thing even heard of, and if yes, how to begin?

Did You hear of someone who did something like this, how did it turn out?

Maybe there is some website that will help or people use Couchsurfing website to do it?

Note: I'm asking mostly about Central Europe, but feel free to say anything You know.

Comment: I have heard of people doing *language* tuition this way, in the distant past, but that's about all

Comment: Sounds like working to me, for which a permit would normally be required. What is your citizenship/current country of residence?

Comment: Similar to an [*au pair*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Au_pair) (with more limited duties)?

Comment: @xngtng thanks, I never heard of "au pair", so it's quite helpful

Comment: @Traveller I have EU citizenship

Comment: You should check the law of the country(ies) you have in mind. In UK it is not yet a legal requirement for a private tutor to hold a DBS certificate (criminal record check) but it might not be far off, and anyway some parents and tutoring agencies will want you to hold one anyway, perhaps both from the UK *and* the equivalent from your country of origin/residence. No responsible parent is going to leave a virtual stranger alone with their child without some assurances.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it is not common.

It may be possible for some people to work their way around Europe by teaching, but most people who want teachers for their kids want someone who is around long term. Someone they can check out before the start of the work and someone they can rely on to be there for a whole school year.

It might be possible in couch surfing, via the official site, or informally organized by traveling to friends of the people you stay with and their friends, but it is very rare.
In 40 years of independent traveling I have met only a hand full and most of them did have some money to travel. (And looking back, the one that did not pay towards the cost was more a beggar than a worker.)

If it was easy to do you would find many posts about it on internet, blogs, questions and answers on many sites and so on. I can not remember seeing any.

That does not say it is impossible, just almost impossible and that makes it a challenge some people can not resist.

(If you do it, make sure you have 'come home money' and a way to contact home to let them know where you are.)